# Android Studio запуск Log cat

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пишу приложение и не хочу каждый раз запускать эмулятор, ноутбук от этого виснет. Можно ли запустить `logcat` без эмулятора?

Comment: Эмулятор можно запустить один раз и не выключать.

Comment: спасибо дружище я так и делаю впринципе )но хочется без него неужели я немогу без эмулятора запустить лог?эклипс в этом плане впереди

Comment: часто при добавлении обновлений эмулятор надо перезапускать .дело ёмкое .использую внешний эмулятор так как свой эмулятор андроида это убожище

Comment: Кстати, не знаю чего многие грешат на встроенный эмулятор. Да, года 2-3 назад он и правда жутко тормозил, однако сейчас работает вполне нормально.

Comment: ты прав с последним обновлением еще лучше стал .но уменя часто бывают ошибки иногда возе незапускается

Comment: Попробуйте Genymotion - он быстрый

Comment: Юрий у меня genymotion спасибо и еще не подскажите остаться на Студио или перейти на Эклипс?

Comment: у меня так часто проблемы со студией чтото отваливается иногда незнаю уже что делать )достали капризы Студии

Comment: Я бы не советовал пользоваться Эклипсом, так как [The Eclipse ADT plugin is no longer supported per our announcement](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).

Comment: теперь ясно )))спасибо!)